# ribbon tab id name is not changed to custom name c#

Tags: c#-4.0, vsto, excel-addins

I have an addin created using VSTO 2010 , first I had created a visual designer and imported to xml. In Visual designer ribbon, the addin was in the idMSo tab and now i want to change the name to the custom addin tab by creating a custom tab by changing

```
<tabs>
  <tab id ="VisMyAddin" label="MyAddin" keytip="G">
    <--<tab idMso="TabAddIns" label="MyAddin" keytip="G">-->
</tabs>
```

and this is not working. Addin is not seen in the addin tab.
How to change this?

Answer (score 0):

May be you are missing this in your Addin class.

```
protected override Microsoft.Office.Core.IRibbonExtensibility CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject()
{
   return new Ribbon1();
}
```